# Mysql crashes on fresh installation

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-5.7, crash, mysqld

I try to run `mysqld` and here's the dump I get:

https://pastebin.com/TCk2YWQN

I tried re-installing mysql, but the same thing happens. Just running `mysql` returns `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: The line `2017-07-17T14:58:36.227339Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.` in your log is telling you what you should look for. Somewhere, one  of the directories needed by MySQL does not have the proper access rights for the *mysql* process.  Under which user is the process running?

Comment: This line, error code 13 is permissions. '2017-07-17T14:58:36.227312Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.'

Comment: Yes always look for [ERROR] part and work towards fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing mysql completely and also deleting all databases. You probably don't want to do this in a prod server or with live data.